# Ajax goes always in error section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, request

I have the following Ajax call on `click()`, **The record deletes from the database table**, But the ajax error section code executes, Not the success section. Also i do get an error of 405,

[image: Error Message]

But the records gets delete, Following is the code.

```
$(".DeleteUser").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var token = $(this).data("token");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "users/"+id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "_method": 'DELETE',
            "_token": token,
        },
        success: function ()
        {
            console.log("it Work");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });

    console.log("It failed");
});
```

Server Side Code :

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $user = $this->find($id);
    $user->delete();
    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'User has been Deleted !',
        'alert-type' => 'success',
    );
    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

Comment: http 405 means server not allowing the code to execute.How deleting the record is possible

Comment: check server logs. the error is called because your server says its an error with statuscode 405

Comment: Can you provide the server side script which receives the delete request and does the processes? If db query is run successfully that means there are some other functionalities which are causing the server to return 405 error.

Comment: I think client sends a `DELETE` request but no method exists in the server side whose type is `DELETE`. Can't fully assure, could you please provide your server side code too. @Comrade

Comment: That all your server code? where is the function called?

Comment: You can try in your ajax code `type: 'GET',` and let me know the status.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Its a resource controller.

Comment: @md.saifurrahman Its a resource controller, So my method should be Delete.

Comment: In the console error log the id is not being passed in the url. Please check whether is ajax request is sent with the id

Comment: The `methodNotAllowed` exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

You have used 'type: "DELETE" '.  Instead of that you should USE 'type:"post"' . You can also use 'get'

Answer (score 0):

you are not ending  your response.But redirecting to some other page.

Skip that redirection and end the request-response cycle.

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $user = $this->find($id);
    $user->delete();
    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'User has been Deleted !',
        'alert-type' => 'success',
    );
    //return redirect()->route('users.index'); //skip it
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($notification);
}
```